# .NET 4.5.2 How can I implement time based events like saving a page to PDF in my website?

Tags: c#, .net

I'm making a .NET website that needs to save PDF versions of my webpages at certain times in the day. I've found the timer class and ways to generate PDF's of my web pages, but my question is which file in .NET do I need to modify so that my timer will run live with the website?

Comment: Take a look at the [Quartz.NET library](http://www.quartz-scheduler.net/), sounds like it's exactly what you need. You shouldn't use the `Timer` class for this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To put it simply put the timer code in a class file with a public method to start the timer. Then call that timer start method within the global.asax code's  "Application_Start" method and it should work.

Please mark the answer if it helps. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you that does help answer my initial noob question. Somebody else pointed out that quartz.net might be a good option.